# What design pattern to avoid overloading functions

Tags: java, design-patterns

I am currently writing a program that turns a String into an int
I got my own rules example : ("37dsqff" = 37) ("50 km/h" = 50)
The problem is the String can be any kind (StringBuffer, Vector, InputStream...) and i don't have any control on it.

So far I have made 1 parseInt() function for each one.
It looks this way :

```
public class Tools {


    public static int parseInt(StringBuffer s)
    {
        ...
        return n;
    }
    public static int parseInt(Vector<Character> v)
    {
        ...
        return n;
    }
    ....
}
```

I have noticed that every functions share too much similarities and I would like to use a design pattern to make it better and only have 1 parseInt function

I think about Visitor, template method but i don't know what s the best here.

Comment: I don't think any design pattern can help avoiding overloading, Inheritance + Factory can be of your help, but I would be an overkill for this problem.

Comment: I would say better to club those common code into another function and invoke that instead of trying to solve over-loading. It would unnecessarily be an overkill.

Comment: i.e. you could use a common private method for the duplicated code (i.e. String -> int) and only vary in the parsing to String

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest (and generally simplest) technique is to find common interfaces and see if you can implement your function at that more general level.

Something like:

```
public static class Tools {

    // CharSequence covers both String and StringBuilder.
    public static int parseInt(CharSequence s) {
        return 4;
    }

    // Use Iterable instead of Vector (Vector implements List).
    public static int parseInt(Iterable<Character> v) {
        return 6;
    }

}
```

Once complete you can take it a little further by writing adaptors that transform one structure into another. This will make an `Iterable<Character>` out of a `CharSequence`.

```
// Make an Iterable<Character> from a CharSequence.
public static class CharWalker implements Iterable<Character> {

    final CharSequence s;

    public CharWalker(CharSequence s) {
        this.s = s;
    }

    @Override
    public Iterator<Character> iterator() {
        return new Iterator<Character>() {
            int i = 0;

            @Override
            public boolean hasNext() {
                return i < s.length();
            }

            @Override
            public Character next() {
                return s.charAt(i++);
            }

        };
    }

}
```

So now we can fold the two together into one:

```
public static class Tools {

    // CharSequence covers both String and StringBuilder.
    public static int parseInt(CharSequence s) {
        // Forward to the Iterable version below.
        return parseInt(new CharWalker(s));
    }

    // Use Iterable instead of Vector (Vector implements List).
    public static int parseInt(Iterable<Character> v) {
        return 6;
    }

}
```